# What is in the packed Maven index (nexus-maven-repository-index.gz)?

Tags: maven, nexus, artifactory, archiva, maven-indexer

Where can I find some more details on what is contained in a Maven repository's Maven Index? Where can one find more details on how this all works? I am somewhat familiar with the [maven-indexer](https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer/), but I still have some grey spots...

What is the difference between the unpacked and packed indexes?

Does a Maven proxy repository have just the remote's index, or does it also keep an index of what artifacts it currently has cached locally?

A thorough and sufficiently lengthy reply would be highly appreciated, as I'm researching the topic and there's, unfortunately, little documentation about it.

Comment: I've created a tag on Stackoverflow with some really useful links here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/maven-indexer/info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a good amount of info on it here, with some more nerdier details: [Nexus Indexer 2.0: incremental downloading](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/05/nexus-indexer-20-incremental-downloading/)

To get started with your questions, the nexus-maven-repository-index.gz contains all of the content for the repository. Using Central as an example, this would be EVERYTHING in central. Alongside this index, an incremental index is also generated that has all the changes since the last time the index was run. A list of these is stored in nexus-maven-repository-index.properties. These incremental indexes are there so that the full index does not need to be downloaded all the time.

Unpacked indexes are used for searching/browse remote functionality, packed indexes are used for transfer from the remote to the proxy/tool.

A Maven proxy repository can download the remote index if available mainly for browsing the remote's assets. This occurs in Nexus Repository 2, but not in 3. In 3, the index is downloaded and can be used by Dev tools to explore the remotes contents, the biggest difference being we don't use it to populate anything inside of Nexus Repository itself. Searches by Maven will be run against the remote index if available, and then the local index.

Proxies in Nexus Repository Manager keep an index of their own, and will download the remote index if it exists. The local will contain the contents locally, the remote will contain the content of the remote.

The gz file is simply a means of storing the lucene index contents for transfer, which is unpacked upon retrieval and put into the local lucene index. The contents are not actual lucene indexes, just the contents, to protect against future lucene version updates.

A packed index is generated with you run certain tasks in Nexus Repository Manager, such a Publish Index. This runs based on whatever schedule you determine.

For group repositories an index would be created from all the member indexes, which would include remote indexes if available, otherwise all local indexes that we know about.

Regardless of repository type, the lucene index is what is checked when doing a search.

Some extra blog posts about the Indexer:

- [Nexus Indexer API: Part 1](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/06/nexus-indexer-api-part-1/)
- [Nexus Indexer API: Part 2](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/06/nexus-indexer-api-part-2/)
- [Nexus Indexer API: Part 3](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/09/nexus-indexer-api-part-3/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How does this work for group/virtual repositories? Do proxy repositories keep an index of their own cached artifacts, apart of that from the remote's index? What is the compressed .gz file actually? Is it a compressed index, or something else? Is the index of a hosted repository used for searching, or is the file system checked first?

Comment: I'll add those as answers as I get them. Explained that the proxy will create a local index in the original answer.

Comment: When is the packed index generated? Is it at the end of an index regeneration for the whole repository, or is it at a scheduled time?

Comment: Thanks for these even more details! So, if the packed index is not really a Lucene index, what is it? How can it be dumped for example? Say I have only a few artifacts in it... Could you please provide a code example of how to do this?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have much time to write a full code sample, but there is a plethora of information available here in the project, and I think the following method might be a good reference point: https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer/blob/a7aeb9f2fe34e6c9f5222bcc2e31f43442cdf99c/indexer-examples/indexer-examples-basic/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/indexer/examples/BasicUsageExample.java#L325