# How to block intellij idea from building huge nexus indexes in /tmp

Tags: intellij-idea

I just found out, that Intellij idea builds index of nexus repository, and puts it in /tmp in default configuration. In my case if found out, that it takes 7G of ram from me, which is far from acceptable. Is there a way how to controll this behavior or turn this feature off. I undestand, that it is probably needed by some functionality, but 7G is way too much.

```
3.0G    nexus-maven-repository-index.gz2870725737868948664
4.0G    nexus-maven-repository-index.gz289507210603911153.dir
```

Comment: It's an index of the whole repository, so 7GB is OK. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511506/8203759

Comment: I got it, that for index it's OK size. Space shuttle consumption of 11,000 pounds of fuel per second is also just fine and understandable, however such consumption in Toyota Camry might raise someones eyebrow. That being said, I'd say, that wasting 7G of RAM for nexus repository index on desktop machine, which in optimistic situation will have 32G of RAM nowadays, is far from reasonable. I might be wrong, but how to turn this off? I need RAM for other stuff. At least how to specify where to put these files, so I can put it on ssd/hdd drive.